# Binding combobox in a DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

I've got the following model class set as the source of my `DataGrid`:

```
public class AttributesModel
    {
        public string Field { get; private set; }

        [Display(Name = "Sort Order")]
        public SortOrder SortBy { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Group By")]
        public string GroupBy { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Having")]
        public string Having { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Display Order")]
        public string DisplayOrder { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Aggregate By")]
        public Aggregate AggregateBy { get; set; }

        public enum Aggregate
        {
            None,
            Sum,
            Minimum,
            Maximum,
            Average
        }

        public enum SortOrder
        {
            Unsorted,
            Ascending,
            Descending
        }

        public AttributesModel(string field)
        {
            Field = field;
        }
    }
```

I'm basically trying to bind the columns in my DataGrid, with the prpoerties above.  They all work except for the `enums` which are set up for the combo box columns.

I cannot seem to get the comboboxes to bind.  This is what I've tried:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Width="Auto" CanUserResize="False" CanUserReorder="False" CanUserSort="False" IsReadOnly="False" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=AttributesWindow, Path=SortOrder}">
                    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.Header>Order</DataGridComboBoxColumn.Header>
                </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

Comment: Exactly what is AttributesWindow? Is it the UIElement? Does it have the SortOrderList property on it? Or do you need to navigate the path DataContext.SortOrderList?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ItemsSource expects an `IEnumerable` value, `enum` is not `IEnumerable`. Try this:

```
public IEnumerable<SortOrder> SortOrderList
{
    get { return Enum.GetValues(typeof(SortOrder)).Cast<SortOrder>(); }
}
```

Comment: I've just tried this but i've still got no luck. I'm calling like this: ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=AttributesWindow, Path=SortOrderList}"

Comment: Just do <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SortOrderList}" /> assuming AttributesModel is set as your DataContext in the code behind.